# Python typed dict with 1 type A value, and all others values of type B?

Tags: python, dictionary, mypy, typing

After looking at the [TypedDictionary documentation of MyPy](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/more_types.html#typeddict), I learned one can specify the types of values of specific keys with:

```py
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

Movie = TypedDict('Movie', {'name': str, 'year': int})

movie: Movie = {'name': 'Blade Runner', 'year': 1982}
```

However, how does one specify the type for 1 variable, for example, the `name` of a movie is of type string, and whatever else you add, is of type `int`?

A bit like:

```py
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

Movie = TypedDict('Movie', {'name': str, '*': int})

# Works:
movie: Movie = {'name': 'Blade Runner', 'year': 1982, 'nr_of_pancakes_in_movie': 42}

# Fails
movie: Movie = {'name': 'Blade Runner', 'year': 1982, 'nr_of_pancakes_in_movie': "seven"}
```

Since I received feedback on whether I should or shouldn't do this, I thought I could include the case on which I am applying this. The thing I am applying it to, is a set of graphs, of which 1 graph, the input graph`is of type`networkx.graph`whereas the others are of type`networkx.DiGraph`. Each graph has a name, yet I do not in advance know which graphs will be added to the dictionary.

The set of graphs gets passed around and it has quite a bit of nested elements that are processed and manipulated, so I would like to keep the depth of the `graphs_dict` constant to make it easier to perform multiple operations on the graphs that are applied to both types.

Comment: Please stop trying to do typescript (where `dict` analogue is first-class, so it is a useful feature `{[key: string]: number}` or `Record<string, number>`) in python. It is not possible. If you need this, then most probably you want *two* dictionaries (first - with typed keys, a TypedDict, and second - a `dict[str, int]`), or another key with type `rest: dict[str, int]` or a even a (data)class instead of typeddict with an item `rest: dict[str, int]` .

Comment: However, you can tweak it if you **really** have to, [like this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.10&gist=516101a9b5a1b378d516b4a436c7d1f8) (gist mine)

Comment: @SUTerliakov thank you for indicating it is not natively supported by Python. I assume this is a language design choice. I think this choice comes down to: different types in a typeddict are ok, as long as you know, in advance, exactly what the names of the keys of the dict will be. Is there a place where I can read where and how this design choice is made? Or is this not even a Python design choice, but rather a choice of e.g. `mypy` or some other package?

Answer (score 0):

You say you want a data type that has one element of a specific type and an open number of other elements of another type.

That sounds more like:

```
MyGraph = TypedDict('MyGraph ': {'graph': networkx.graph, di_graphs: List[networkx.DiGraph]})
```

The natural solution is to use a list for the open number of elements, it can have 0 or more elements, and the type is clear here.

It does seem like you're trying to bolt features from other languages onto Python though, which Python doesn't need - or if you do need them, you may not find Python the best choice.